# How to delete a building in pixel people

Tags: pixel-people

Once I have a worker assigned to a building, how do I remove the worker so I can remove the structure?  You can't seem to fire workers and you can't delete a structure that has them. In this case I'd rather not have a stadium but an athlete is already in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, unless there is another place your worker can move to, you simply can't.
A good alternative would be to move the stadium as far away from the rest of your stuff as possible, but I believe that is the best you can do.

Comment: I've found that there is a "building firm" company that, once built, will allow you to replicate buildings or delete empty ones.  The interesting thing is that there seems to be no way to remove workers or send them back to be re spliced.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd share this here, to to answer half of the question in case people are still looking at this:

> "A vital addition to the townscape, the building firm houses the
>   blueprints required to replicate any of the structures sent down by
>   the mothership. **Buildings can also be deleted so long as they are not
>   one of a kind.** TRIVIA: The interiors department was founded by gifted
>   designer Chen De'Liah."

From [Building Firm - Pixel People Wiki](http://pixelpeople.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Firm).

Also, here's a screenshot from my game, showing that a message "Cannot delete the only building left" appears at the top when when I try to delete a building, of which I only have one:

[image: Here]

So, while **copies of a building** can be deleted, the original cannot.

This is still true as of update 1.60 (Oct 23, 2013)